# Load image from jar and outside it in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I have a structure like this in my java project in eclipse:

- src/com/myprogram/.../foo.java
- res/icon.png
- .project
- ...

I Know that you can load an image from inside a jar with

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/icon.png"));
```

The problem come when you try to run the application with eclipse directly as (I guess) res folder isn't inside src folder, you get a `null` `URL`. And I want to have separate folders for source code and for resources.

Also, what I have found is that I can add `res` folder to class-path in eclipse so I can load it with:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/icon.png");
if (url == null)
    url = getClass().getResource("/icon.png");
ImageIO.read(url);
```

But this add code that is only needed when you develop, and I don't like do things like this (code should be as clean and final as possible).

Can something done so the icon is read with both methods with the same code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `resources` folder in your project, mark it as a source folder in eclipse, put the `res` folder under `resources`, and make sure your non-eclipse build uts everything that is under `resources` in the jar. Then load the icon using

```
getClass().getResource("/res/icon.png")
```

Your problem is caused by the fact that you non-eclipse build puts `res` in the jar, but eclipse puts the *content* of `res` in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your res folder as a source folder (project properties > source > add folder).

Everything in this folder will be available on the classpath.