# creating Executable Jar with input file on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

I am trying to create an runnable Jar on eclipse.

After creation, Eclipse give me error message saying that its was created with compiler error.

When I ran it on the command line, it throw IOException, saying that I cannot find the input file.

I have file path within the project to read number of .jpg files.

I think these are not included for some reason when it creates the Jar file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is how I'm Accessing the files in my code

```
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/images/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
            file = new File("src/images/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");

        read = new Scanner(new File("intensity.txt"));
```

Comment: you are using Windows.?

Comment: Please post the Exception....also make sure you are referring to the correct file path ...!

Comment: What do you mean by the correct file path? Am I not using the correct file path, if it runs fine within eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the images shall be packaged into the final jar file or loaded from some directory. The former will not rely on absolute paths as the latter one *might*, while the latter one allows easier adding of images or exchanging them -- but that really depends on what you need. (There may be many other caveats/advantages/disadvantages... you name it. Searching on stackoverflow with the right keywords may help you out, but read on)

Running a project from within eclipse sets up several things like classpath and the working directory is usually set to the project's base path. Hence, the executable may "incidentially" find the images. It may not always be that obvious what eclipse does. I suggest you have a look at and make yourself familiar with the "run configurations".

If you want to include the files into the jar-file, you may also have to adapt the project's *Java Build Path* >> *Order and Export* settings to include the image directory.

You may also want to have a look at the following Q/A: [Load image from jar and outside it in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085692/load-image-from-jar-and-outside-it-in-eclipse)